# How to stop a on demand webjob

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an on demand web job thats scheduled using the cron expression. I have tried analyzing the REST API. It provides option to stop a continuosly runing webjob. Is there a way to stop this webjob when its running?

Answer (score 7):

For OnDemand CRON jobs, currently the way to stop the job is to temporarily remove the schedule from the settings.job file. Analogously, if you were using Azure Scheduler to invoke your job, the way to stop the job would be to stop the schedule in Azure Scheduler. An alternative to removing the schedule from the file would be to rename your settings.job file to **settings.job.disable** or to rename the `schedule` property in the settings.job which leaves your CRON expression intact but disabled (e.g. `"schedule.disabled": "0 */30 * * * *"`).

It would probably be better for us to support a "**disabled**" property in settings.job that you can set (e.g. `"disabled": true`). This way the schedule remains in place and is only temporarily deactivated.

Comment: Also, setting `WEBJOBS_STOPPED=1` in the Azure App Settings will stop all CRON scheduled jobs (but not those coming from scheduler, as that comes externally).

Comment: @David Ebbo Does that setting stop all CRON in the web app?

Comment: @Mathewc Effectively that means without doing another deployment this is not achievable? Any possibilities through power shell?

Comment: The file modifications I mentioned are the only options right now. You might consider logging an issue here detailing your scenario: github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues.

Comment: Another option - You could use the WebJobs SDK, which also supports triggering job functions on schedule, based on the same CRON expression format. See TimerTrigger in https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions. In conjunction with that, the WebJobs SDK also has a DisableAttribute that can be applied to functions, that allows you to enable/disable functions based on application settings. You can find more on that in the release notes here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Release-Notes.

Comment: @HariSubramaniam yes, that setting affects everything hosted in that Web App.

Comment: The mentioned file may also be modified with Kudu (<your-website>.scm.azurewebsites.net). In this way no deployment is required.